# Exporting shared gmail inboxes with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-oauth

I have a script where I am able to export data from Gmail into a Google Sheet. It works well for individual inboxes but now I need it to access delegated or shared inboxes. Is there any way I can do this within the script? Using OAuth 2.0 perhaps?

```js
//Create menu select in google sheet
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function onOpen(e) {

  ui.createMenu("Gmail Manager").addItem("Get Emails by Label",
    "getGmailEmails").addToUi();

}

//Allow user to select label(s) and date range
function getGmailEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var label = sheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue();
  var after = sheet.getRange(2, 3).getDisplayValue();
  var before = sheet.getRange(3, 3).getDisplayValue();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:" + label + " AND " + "after:" + after +
    " AND " + "before:" + before);

  // Export emails into table of values in google sheet
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    var label = threads[i].getLabels().map(e => e.getName()).join(",");
    let messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      temp.push([
        label,
        messages[j].getFrom(),
        messages[j].getFrom().replace(/^,+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1"),
        messages[j].getDate(),
        messages[j].getSubject(),
        messages[j].getPlainBody()
      ]);
    }
    values = values.concat(temp);
  }
  sheet.getRange(6, 1, values.length,
    values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is a delegated inbox?

Comment: Delegated inboxes are just shared inboxes

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have access to the user account of the [delegated inbox](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350). If my assumption is correct, then you can run your Apps Script very easily for the delegated account. You only have to copy your script into that account Drive and execute it while logged in. If you want to save the mails into the same Sheet, I advise you to use [`SpreadsheetApp.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid). Please remember to share that Sheet with the delegated inbox account.

Alternatively you could develop your script as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) while setting the `Execute as` property to `User accessing the web app`. Then you only have to execute the web app using the shared Gmail account. With this approach you could scalate your project to multiple accounts efficiently.

Comment: So I do have access to the shared inbox but those accounts don't have a Drive. If I try to login to the shared account I'm redirected to my own account. I believe I need to add some kind of authorization to the script or an API service

Comment: I assume that you added a delegated account following [these steps](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-a-delegate). Is that correct? If not, please share what you did instead.

Comment: Yes that's how it was added. Now I just have trouble pulling information from the shared inbox via apps script.

Comment: I am still able to login into the delegated account after following that doc. I have searched other guides for this situation, and they all could too. If you can't do it I strongly advise you to contact [Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) to receive the appropriate help for your situation.